# How To Plot A Pie Chart Using A Dictionary Of Characters and Numbers

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pie-chart

So ive got some code here, This code takes the species of admitted animal, Associates it with a taxon and counts the taxons. This is done with dictionaries, However, when I go to plot them in a pie chart it's not able to form one.

I'm certain in the fact that the dictionary is: Taxon: #N of occurrences, Taxon: #N of occurrences, etc. So I can just convert it to a float.  But i've attempted to use

```
#imports csv and mathplot
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creates a correlation table as a dict
with open('species_taxon.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf8', newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    correlation = {row['Species']: row['Taxon'] for row in cf}

#then uses it to count the taxons
import collections
with open('Accessions-Jan-2018.csv','r', encoding = 'utf8', newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    count = collections.Counter(correlation.get(row['species'], 'Unknown') for row in cf)
#prints the counted taxons
print(count)
```

When I attempt to use

```py
plt.pie([float(v) for v in count], labels=[float(k) for k in keys], autopct=None)
```

i get the error 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#The name of the Taxon'

Comment: I think the problem just comes from the keys. Have you tried not converting the keys to floats? Like `labels=keys`

Answer (score 2):

```
#Using matplotlib
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
pie, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,6])
Labels = [k for k in methods.keys()]
Data   = [float(v) for v in methods.values()]
plt.pie(x = Data, labels=Labels, autopct="%.1f%%", pctdistance=0.5);
plt.title("Frequency of used moehods", fontsize=14);
```

[Output pie plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHEog.png)

Comment: it is always better to explain your code, so anyone reading your answer understands what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

You need all your labels in `str` instead of `float` :

`plt.pie([float(v) for v in count], labels=[str(k) for k in keys], autopct=None)`